# Dealing with missing module and inverter types with PVLib

Tags: pvlib

I am looking through the SAM and CEC DBs for inverter and module types, as I am looking to do some forecasts.

As I don't find the correct types (SMA 2200CP and Canadian Solar CS6X310M), is there another resource to pull that data or can I create an addition to the dataframe when I export it from `pvlib` in python?

I am new, so please feel to correct me at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pvlib-python should update their cec libraries, but in the meantime, you can download SAM from [sam.nrel.gov](http://sam.nrel.gov), and access their updated libraries packaged with the newest version (2017.01.17 as of this writing). You can then specify those local files with the retrieve_sam function.

Note that the sam.nrel.gov website lists their libraries to be downloaded separately, but those are not the most recent versions. Probably the reason that the pvlib-python libraries haven't been updated is that they just check those files.

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  Specifically to getting updated libraries via SAM (which I have downloaded), how would I call for that in the `retrieve_sam` call?  I see that I can pass in a filepath to `retrieve_sam` but how would I get to the library within the SAM software after I have downloaded it (assuming that SAM doesn't query a library itself).

Comment: Good question. On a Mac, I control clicked on the .App file to check out the Contents of the package, and found CEC Modules.csv and CEC Inverters.csv under the libraries folder. I then copied those csv files to a subdirectory in my python world, and referenced those copies from pvlib-python.